# Deleting duplicate answers on a locked question

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question

The question "[What are good places to post your work where it will be read by others?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/904)" is locked "because it has historical significance, but it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site". It shows that an impressive 45 users have marked it as a favourite.

There are two almost identical answers by the same user, with
[2 votes](https://writing.stackexchange.com/a/6291/21181) and [0 votes](https://writing.stackexchange.com/a/6290/21181). There seems no value whatsoever in retaining the second answer with no votes.

Do moderators have the capacity to remove such an answer on a locked post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, and done.  Thank you for pointing out the duplication.

Comment: Normally I'd have flagged it for moderator attention, but flags aren't possible for locked posts, so I guess Meta where you go to flag these?

Comment: Yeah, not ideal, but without the ability to flag, what else can you do?  Meta's fine.  Thanks for bringing it up.

Comment: There's another duplicate answer (regarding Fictionpress), but the [second answer](https://writing.stackexchange.com/a/6010/21181) has a useful comment. Is it worth copying that comment and adding it (as a comment) to the [first answer](https://writing.stackexchange.com/a/907) so that the second answer can be deleted? Not trying to give you extra work ;-)

Comment: Done.  (We can't move comments directly, but I can convert a post to a comment and bring its comments along for the ride, so I did that and then deleted the comment that was previously the post.)

Comment: Nicely done :-)